# MinGW GCJ libiconv path problem

Tags: java, windows, gcc, mingw

I'm having a problem with the MinGW implementation of GCJ. I read that you have to install libiconv before you can use it. However, the documentation wasn't very specific, and it did not say where to extract the binaries and developer files (libiconv-bin and libiconv-lib). I have tried the following paths:
$p = c:\mingw
$p\libiconv-1.9.2-1-[bin|lib]\
$p\libiconv-[bin|lib]\
$p\mingw32\libiconv-1.9.2-1-[bin|lib]
$p\mingw32[bin|lib]\libiconv
$p\mingw[bin|lib]\liconv
$p\bin\libiconv-1.9.2-1-[bin|lib]
$p\bin\libiconv-[bin|lib]

None of these work. Any help on where I'm supposed to put the libiconv files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the libiconv-* into the same directory as MinGW.

You can extract the libiconv-* into a folder first, then copy all the sub-folders in to your MinGW directory.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain so clear. 
You need to move all the sub-folders {bin,lib,include,man,share} into "c:\MinGW".

Comment: Uh, perhaps a little late, but wouldn't that override the already existant MinGW bin/lib/etc folders?

Comment: @Hussain You should select override, when you copy the files.
Indeed it didn't override anything because you should not have these files at all. :D